# Parent object is too far from children how can I fix it ? Parent is at 0,0,0 but the children in other position/s

Tags: unity

When I make double click on the empty GameObject as it should be it's zooming to the children group :

[image: Npcs]

I grouped all the npcs under emprt GameObject name Npcs but first I was reseting Npcs to 0,0,0 Now the arrows of the axis to drag and change the Npcs positions are far away. The idea was to easy move the npcs all the same time.

When I zoom out in the scene window this is where the Npcs is so if I will drag it and change it's positions I will not see where the npcs are moving to they are too far.

[image: Npcs]

Comment: Have you considered changing your transform gizmo mode from "Pivot" to "Center"? Or simply rearranging your parent so its origin is closer to where you're working?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you have a parent object and under it a few NPC objects, when the NPCs are in the desired place, but the parent is far off.

Try to move your parent object to the **current position of the NPCs** (this will move the NPCs as well), and then move the NPCs (one by one) to their previous location (which is where the parent should be by now).

Comment: A faster way is this: Create a new object (doesn't matter where). Move your NPCs into the new object. Now move your (empty) parent to the location of the NPCs. Finally, move the NPCs back into their original parent and destroy the temporary holding object. This way Unity does the work of preserving their positions, rather than the dev needing to remember where to put them back to.